# Is it possible to have tabs inside a Vim buffer

Tags: vim, vi, neovim

Having multiple tabs in vim I've noticed that when I create a new buffer, this buffer stays inside the tab where I create it. Not being an expert at `vim` I expected the new buffer to behave like a `new chrome window` where I could put more tabs in. Is there a way to have a workspace like this in vim where **when I switch buffers** vim would show me a new set of tabs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: tabs are containers for windows. Windows display buffers. Buffers hold text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't how buffers work. Buffers are containers that hold and facilitate interaction with text. To use your Chrome analogy, this is like asking: *how can I open new windows in my browser tabs?* which of course you can't, beacuse that is not the interface is designed to work.

As I mentioned in the comments: tabs are containers for windows. Windows display buffers. Buffers hold text.

If a higher level of hierarchical abstraction is needed on top of tabs/windows, the best bet<sup>1</sup> is probably to just open a new terminal window and start a separate instance of vim. That is even what is suggested [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Buffers#Managing_buffers). I personally never use tabs, it's too clunky and I find it easier to flip between terminal sessions, which is second nature since I do that all the time anyway. The mechanics of vim tabs don't have that kind of "portability".

---

<sub>1: actually, the *best* bet is to close some of the unnecessary documents. If you're at the point where tabs and windows just aren't enough, adding *more* complexity isn't going to make you more efficient.</sub>